# Order of operation to get total

Tags: arithmetic

Does anyone know the answer for this equation:

$$((6.2 * 4) * ((0.00019106 * 2,715,297.4673) + (0.00226263 * 4,500) + 0.55))\\ * (1 + 0.1 + 0.02 ) / 150 * 10 = ?$$

I also do not understand how it is answered step by step, if you could provide how it is done that would be awesome

Comment: The standard order of operations is: exponents and roots,
multiplication and division, then
addition and subtraction. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Order_of_operations

Answer (score 1):

You can type it into [Alpha](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=%28%286.2%E2%88%974%29%E2%88%97%28%280.00019106%E2%88%972%2C715%2C297.4673%29%2B%280.00226263%E2%88%974%2C500%29%2B0.55%29%29%E2%88%97%281%2B0.1%2B0.02%29%2F150%E2%88%9710) and get $980.5234815591026858\overline{6}$  Do the calculations inside the parentheses first.  That gets you everything you need here (congratulations to the problem setter for having enough parentheses) except whether the end has the $150 *10$ first (which puts the $10$ in the denominator) or divides by $150$ and then multiplies by $10$, (which puts the $10$ in the numerator).  The second is what Alpha follows and is more standard.